# Pandas : Compare columns of dataframe on basis of position and irrespective of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to output the data into multiple sheets that will contain partial filled fields.

Partial Sheet 1:

First 3 are the key columns. I want to compare the columns F5,F6,F7,F8 and get the columns which have data in the same index and delete the rest. There can be N number of columns.

In this case, my output should be in the following format:

[image]

Partial Sheet 2: Will contains Key columns and one field column (F5) without null values.

[image]

Partial Sheet 3: Will contains Key columns and one field column (F7) without null values.

[image]

I tried researching a lot however could not find anything substantial.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Not understand output, what positions is compared? Is specify, how? Why is not returned `z3` row, if data in all columns `F5,F6,F7,F8` ?

Comment: You could not find solution because you have not provided the logic. No one can tell what is happening to your data to be transformed to the output

Comment: OK, thanks for EDIT. `I want to compare the columns F5,F6,F7,F8 and get the columns which have data in the same index and delete the rest. There can be N number of columns.` - why are returned `F6, F8` ? And not `row3` with `F5,F6,F7,F8` ?

Comment: @jezrael - I've updated the post which explains it in a bit more detail. The output excel will contain multiple sheets and only if 2 or more fields match on the basis of position then they will be included in one sheet. Else, they will be included in a new sheet.

Comment: what is `the basis of position` ?

Comment: @jezrael - F6 & F8 are being returned because number of rows with non null values and their indexes match. In other fields it is not the case therefore, they are being outputted in the new sheet.

Comment: I start understand, Need compare `F5` with `F6`, then `F7`, `F8`? Still need comapre 2 columns? Or need compare, 2, 3, 4... N columns toegteher? What is `N`  in real data?

Comment: N will be the Nth column. We need to compare all the F columns F6, F7, F8....Fn to find where number of rows and their index will match and return them in the same sheet. Else return individual columns in a new sheet.

Comment: In real data `N` is `4` ? or `100` ?

Comment: Apologies, the fields will start from F1,F2,F3,F4...FN. Where N can range to 100.

Comment: @Deluxplanet345 - Not easy, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#if missing values are not NaNs
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

#columns from third column
cols = df.columns[3:]

#columns with keys
keycols = df.columns[:3].tolist()

out = cols.copy()
df1 = df.copy()

#in loop create combinations of columns with same index
final_cols = []

for c in out:
    if c in out:
        m = df1[c].notna()
        #test if all columns has not missing values like tested column
        #and also test if rows with missing values like tested column are missed too
        c1=out[df.loc[m, out].notna().all()].intersection(out[df.loc[~m, out].isna().all()])
    
        df1 = df1.drop(c1, axis=1)
        out = out.difference(c1)
        final_cols.append(c1.tolist())

#finally sorted list of columns by length
final_cols = sorted(final_cols, key=len, reverse=True)
```

---

```
#create excel with multiple sheets
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for c in final_cols:
        df[keycols + c].dropna(subset=c).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{"_".join(c)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Full code

```
cols = df.filter(like='F').replace('', pd.NA).stack().reset_index(0).groupby(level=0)['level_0'].agg(frozenset) 
common = cols.reset_index().groupby('level_0')['index'].agg(list).to_list()
extra = ['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3']
for c in common:
    print(f'data_cols_{"-".join(c)}.csv')
    print(df.loc[cols[c[0]], extra+c])
```

###### Details

###### step1

You can first use aggregation as frozensets to identify the non-NA indices per column:

```
cols = (df
 .filter(like='F').replace('', pd.NA)
 .stack().reset_index(0)
 .groupby(level=0)['level_0'].agg(frozenset) 
)
```

output:

```
F5    (2, 3, 4, 5)
F6    (0, 1, 2, 3)
F7          (1, 2)
F8    (0, 1, 2, 3)
Name: level_0, dtype: object
```

###### step2

Then aggregate again to group the columns with the same indices:

```
common = cols.reset_index().groupby('level_0')['index'].agg(list).to_list()
# [['F5'], ['F7'], ['F6', 'F8']]
```

###### step3

Finally, slice and export:

```
extra = ['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3']
for c in common:
    print(f'data_cols_{"-".join(c)}.csv')
    df.loc[cols[c[0]], extra+c].to_csv(f'data_cols_{"-".join(c)}.csv')
```

output:

```
data_cols_F5.csv
  Key1 Key2 Key3 F5
2   x3   y3   z3  a
3   x4   y4   z4  a
4   x5   y5   z5  a
5   x6   y6   z6  a

data_cols_F7.csv
  Key1 Key2 Key3 F7
1   x2   y2   z2  c
2   x3   y3   z3  c
data_cols_F6-F8.csv

  Key1 Key2 Key3 F6 F8
0   x1   y1   z1  b  d
1   x2   y2   z2  b  d
2   x3   y3   z3  b  d
3   x4   y4   z4  b  d
```

###### used input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6'],
                   'Key2': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5', 'y6'],
                   'Key3': ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'z4', 'z5', 'z6'],
                   'F5': ['', '', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'F6': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', '', ''],
                   'F7': ['', 'c', 'c', '', '', ''],
                   'F8': ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', '', '']})
```

###### comparison of the different answers:

on 60k rows

```
# mozway
69.3 ms ± 7.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# jezrael
122 ms ± 9.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

on 600k rows:

```
# mozway
747 ms ± 69.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# jezrael
1.32 s ± 61.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Have you have a chance to test this answer? I believe it is not only simpler but more efficient than the alternative.